# Editing shapefiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have shapefiles which were created in ArcGIS Desktop and I want to edit them in QGIS.

If this is possible, how do I open and edit shapefiles in QGIS?

Comment: Sure you can.... just try and read the doc.

Comment: Before downvoting here: In my opinion this is a question of axiomatic meaning, and obviously this is not 'a-priori' clear to all gis newcomers, that are told about ESRI shapefiles. But indeed, I do not know any GISses that can't edit shapefiles (except GE Smallworld, but that's another story...). In fact, shapefiles are the 'smallest common denominator' for exchanging spatial data between various systems.

Comment: Editing a shapefile in QGIS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGFAMv4sUh0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows very little research effort.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, editing shapefiles is a very common task for any GIS, including QGIS. While Esri developed the shapefile, it is an open standard that can be used by nearly every GIS platforms.

The editing tools are in the "digitizing" toolbar. The pencil button starts an editing session. From there you can edit the attributes of a feature, or the vector geometry.

I would start here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/index.html

And this is the best tutorial that I have found:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/index.html